# IPC connection with thread on Windows using Mutex

Tags: c++, windows, ipc

I have a question about Windows IPC. I implemented IPC with mutex on Windows, but there is a problem when I made the connection with another thread;when the thread terminated, the connection is closed.

1. The connection thread(A) makes connection to the server
2. Main thread(B) uses the connection handle(global variable) returned by A
3. A terminates
4. B cannot refer the handle any more - because connection is closed

It is natural that mutex is released when the process terminated. However, in the case of thread, I need the way to hold mutex to maintain connection even though the thread terminated, if the process is alive.

Semaphore can be the alternative on Linux, however, on Windows, it is impossible to use semaphor because it cannot sense the abnormal disconnection.

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: A mutex is a synchronization object, not an IPC object.  What do you mean by "connection to the server"?

Comment: The client program above connects to the server(DB) via IPC. Mutexes are used to maintaion IPC connections. For instance, if the client is holding mutex, the server knows that the connection is alive. On the other hand, if the client releases the mutex, the server realizes that the communication is disconnected. In the case above, thread A makes the connection(holds mutex), but terminates after connection(releases mutex by termination), so thread B cannot do anything with handle.

Comment: Does the client need to close the connection (by releasing the mutex) explicitly?  If not, and if you can get a handle to the client process, you could just wait until the client process exits.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your question. Anyway, client needs to close connection explicitly only when it is necessary. However, in the aforesaid case, the connection closed implicitly since the mutex of client(which server checks to confirm connection) released by termination of connection thread. As you said the handled should be maintained until process exits. The easist way to solove problem may be making connection with thread B(Main thread), not using A(connection thread), but we have to connect using thread, and the connection should be maintained until the process(thread B) ends.

Comment: You're still confusing owning of the mutex with having a handle to it.  The handle is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent the ownership of a mutex from being released when the thread that owns it exits.

There are a number of other ways you might be able to fix the problem, depending on the circumstances.

1) Can you change any of the code on the client?  For example, if the client executable is using a DLL that you have provided to establish and maintain the connection, you could change the DLL so that it uses a more appropriate object (such as a named pipe) rather than a mutex, or you could get the DLL to start its own thread to own the mutex.

2) Is there more than one client?  Presumably, since you are using a mutex, you are only expecting one client to connect at a time.  If you can safely assume that only one client will be connected at a time, then when the server detects that the mutex has been abandoned, it could close its own handle to the mutex.  When the client process exits, the mutex will automatically be deleted, so the server could periodically check to see whether it still exists or not.

3) How is the client communicating with the server?  The server is presumably doing something useful for the client, so there must be another communications channel as well as the mutex.  For example, if the client is opening a named pipe to the server, you could use that connection instead of the mutex to detect when the client process exits.  Or, if the communications channel allows you to determine the process ID of the client, you could open a handle to the process and use that to detect when the client process exits.

4) If no other solution will work, and you are forced to rewrite the client as well as the server, consider using a more appropriate form of IPC, such as a named pipe.

*Additional*

5) It is common practice to use a process handle to wait for (or test for) process termination.  Most often, these handles are the ones generated for the parent when a process is created, but there is no reason not to use a handle generated by OpenProcess.  As far as precedent goes, I assure you there is at least as much precedent for using a handle generated by OpenProcess to monitor a client process as there is for using a mutex; it is entirely possible that you are the first person to ever try to use a Windows mutex to detect that a process has exited. :-)

6) Presumably the SQLDisconnect() function is calling [ReleaseMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to disconnect from the server.  Since it is doing so from a thread that doesn't own the mutex, that won't do anything except return an error code, so there's no reasonable way for your server to detect that happening.  Does the function also call [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the mutex?  If so, you could use the approach in (2) to detect when this happens.  This would work both for calls to SQLDisconnect() and when the process exits.  It shouldn't matter that there are multiple clients, since they are using different mutexes.

6a) I say "no reasonable way" because you could conceivably use [hooking](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D%20hooking) to change the behaviour of ReleaseMutex.  ***This would not be a good option.***

7) You should examine carefully what the SQLDisconnect() function does apart from calling ReleaseMutex and/or CloseHandle.  It is entirely possible that you can detect the disconnection by some means other than the mutex.

Comment: 1) It is difficult to modify client application. The users want to use their client application without modifying anything. 2) Since the server is a kind of DB, many clients can connect to the server simultaneously. The connections were managed by the array of mutexes. And in this case, it is still a problem that mutexes are automatically released by thread termination.

Comment: 3) In fact I was trying this way - to get process ID from client and hold it using fuctions like OpenProcess(). But I'm not sure that there were any precedents of implement like this. Also, server annot confirm disconnection of client in case that the client terminated by calling function like SQLDisconnect(), because process would be still alive.

Comment: (See additional notes added to my answer.)  So each connection has a different mutex associated with it.  Who creates the mutex for a particular connection, the client, or the server?  How is the name of the mutex negotiated?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But I understood that OpenProcess can be a good alternative of mutexes to detect abnormal disconnection. But it seems to be difficult to detect normal disconnection, which means that the process may be alive and used for another connections, since OpenProcess can monitor the existence of the process. It is the problem of using OpenProcess instead of Mutex.

Comment: Does SQLDisconnect() close the handle to the mutex?

Comment: No, it just releases mutex, so handle should be closed later.

Comment: If the client does not close the handle, then I think you're stuck.  Unless you can find some other behaviour in SQLDisconnect() that the server can detect, your only options are to change the client or put up with the fact that the client can't disconnect from the server.

Comment: Maybe that would be the only solution. Thank you for your help. Well, I'm thinking of sending events but I'm not sure it will work well.

Comment: A named pipe is probably the best option (even if you never send any actual data through the pipe) since they are connection-oriented.  It is easy to detect when the other end of a named pipe is closed, regardless of whether this was because the process exited or because it explicitly closed the pipe.  (Also, named pipes are thread-independent.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Named pipe seems to solve those problems well. By the way, I have a one more question. What would be the best way to detect disconnection of client? I thought to use WaitForSingleObject(), but this function does not support the handle for pipes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Issue a read operation (asynchronous if you like) and look for the appropriate error code, I forget which one offhand.

Comment: I used WaitForSingleObject() function with event, and it seems to work fine. Anyway, thank you for your advice.